# Technique to AJAX-ify this Django app

Tags: python, ajax, django

I've been trying to develop a django app for handling bar tabs... So far I can add tabs, add products to a tab, and delete products from a tab. Now, I wanted to use AJAX on the adding/removing products from a tab, and I don't know if I needed to use a form or not... Here is what I have so far:

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length='70')
  price = models.FloatField()
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Tab(models.Model):
  number = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length='50')
  tabdate = models.DateTimeField('date created')
  consumed = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ConsumedRelation')
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class ConsumedRelation(models.Model):
  tab = models.ForeignKey(Tab)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.product)
```

**views.py**

```
def addproduct(request, number, product):
  tab = Tab.objects.get(number=number)
  product = Product.objects.get(id=product)
  add = ConsumedRelation.objects.create(product=product, tab=tab, count=1)
  add.save()
  context = {'tab': tab, 'product': product}
  return render_to_response('addproduct.html', context)

def deleteproduct(request, number, consumedid):
  tab = Tab.objects.get(number=number)
  ConsumedRelation.objects.filter(id=consumedid).delete()
  context = {'tab': tab}
  return render_to_response('deleteproduct.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tabs/(?P<number>[0-9].*)/delete/(?P<consumedid>[0-9].*)/$', 'barcomandas.views.deleteproduct'),
url(r'^tabs/(?P<number>[0-9].*)/add/(?P<product>[0-9].*)/$', 'barcomandas.views.addproduct'),
```

**singletab.html**

```
<h1>{{ tab.name }} | {{ tab.number }}</h1>
<h2>Consumed</h2>
{% for consumed in consumedlist %}
<a href="delete/{{ consumed.id }}">X</a>{{ consumed }}<br/>
{% endfor %}

<div id="addproducts">
{% for product in productlist %}
<li><a href="add/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**addproduct.html**

```
{{ product }} added to tab {{ tab.name }}
```

So for example, when I add some product, I have a useless page "product added to tab" because I can't do it without some html page so I can use the view. Does that make sense?
But I don't want to make this as a form because this will be used in a 7" tablet and I'm gonna have good sized buttons for each product since the bar I'm working can get very very busy sometimes, so I need that kind of speed.

Ideally I would have ajax on everything, with a list of the current open tabs on the left, and the tab-editing on the right column, with options to add products, close tab, and etc.
So what I would want is, there's the list of the products in singletab.html, with a "X" to the side of each product. You click on the X, the product fades, and the list and everything else is updated, without reloading the page.

Do you guys see any solution to that? Sorry about my english, not my main language.

PS: 
This is also my first django app, so I'm sorry for any stupid mistakes..
Would a simple jquery get on for example (/tabnumber/add/product) be enough? And how would I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I didn't understand your question properly except below lines.

> there's the list of the products in singletab.html, with a "X" to the side of each product. You click on the X, the product fades, and the list and everything else is updated, without reloading the page.

I think you can try using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). Its Javascript library that makes life easier for event handling and ajaxifying of pages.

For your fade out example you can see [w3 example which is good place to start learning about JQuery.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadeout) you can also refer [Ajax with JQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) to understand how to use Ajax with JQuery.

Hopefully, it helps you or take you a step ahead..Best of luck :-)